# How can I prevent apache to log ELB Health Checks in Docker?

Tags: docker, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

I have a dockerized web application deployed in ECS, and everything works just fine, logging  in cloudwatch every request, including a HUGE number of health checks, which are configured to hit the page `/health`, a blank page.

I'd like to have a solution that is completely automatic and possibly in the `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I need an additional configuration file for Apache, let's call it `apacheLogFilter.conf`.

The content will be pretty easy, but it could be customized as much as we want, defining custom rules. The trick is defining a custom environment variable that, if present, will stop the logging for that request

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/health$" dontlog
```

Once defined this new configuration, we need to plug it into apache directly in the `Dockerfile`, adding the following rows:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

...

# Copy the log-filtering configuration in the right place
COPY  apacheLogFilter.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled

# Change the standard logging entry of all the available sites to use the variable 
RUN sed -ri -e 's!combined!combined env=\!dontlog!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf

...
```

In this way, the configuration file will be loaded by apache at startup, each request will check the rules defined, and in case one of them will trigger, the request will not be logged